# Show that $n^{1/n}$ is eventually decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that $$ a_n=n^{1\over n}$$
is eventually decreasing.

I am not allowed to used derivatives and I have been trying for a while. I graphed it and it is decreasing if $n>2$, but how can you show it?

I have tried to look at ${a_{n+1}/a_n}$ but it gets me nowhere.

Comment: $$n^{\frac{1}{n}} > (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \iff n^{n+1} > (n+1)^n$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $(n-1)^n\gt n^{n-1}$, which is easily verified for $n=4$.  Then

$$n^{n+1}
=n\left(n\over(n-1)\right)^n(n-1)^n
\gt \left({n^2\over n-1}\right)^n
=\left({n^2-1+1\over n-1}\right)^n
=\left(n+1+{1\over n-1}\right)^n
\gt(n+1)^n$$

The first inequality uses the induction hypothesis; the second uses the fact that $n\gt1$.

Comment: You have an extra $n$ that should not be there after the first inequality sign.

Comment: @VincentPfenninger, are you referring to the initial $n$, before the term that's raised to the $n$th power?  If so, I left it there intentionally; its removal gives the second inequality.

Comment: After using the induction hypothesis you are left with $n\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^nn^{n-1} = \left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^nn^{n} = \left(\frac{n^2}{n-1}\right)^n$.

Comment: Oh gosh, you're quite right.  I'll fix it.  Thank you!

Comment: This proof doesn't seem right to me. The usage of induction proves this only for integer values of n

Answer (score 1):

Show that if $n\geq 3$ then $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<n.$$

You can actually show by elementary means (without logarithms, calculus, or $e$, just binomial theorem and some simple inequalities) that:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\leq 3$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution follows [Daniel Fischer's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) hint.

Using the inequality (for $x \ne 0$)
$$
1 + x < e^x,
$$
with $x = 1/n$, we have
$$
\frac{n+1}{n} \le e^{1/n}.
$$
But for $n \ge 3 > e$
$$
e^{1/n} < n^{1/n}.
$$
So
$$
\frac{n+1}{n} < n^{1/n},
$$
or
$$
n+1 < n^{\frac{n+1}{n}},
$$
Taking the $(n+1)$th root yields the desired result.

Comment: Oh that was a great help from you